# Android: How to put Class type in a Bundle?

Tags: android, bundle

Is it possible to put a Class type in a Bundle ?

```
public static <T> Intent newInstance(Class<T> EventClass) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putXXXX(EventClass);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.getInstance(), MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(args);
    return intent;
}
```

Thanks guys !

Comment: You can try `putSerializable()`, as `Class` implements `Serializable`, but I am skeptical that what you are doing is a good idea.

Comment: You could use a singleton pattern to store and retrieve an instance of your custom class instead, check this out: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use `Class<T>.getCanonicalName()` and then instantiate the class by that name when reading it from the Bundle.

The scenario makes sense if for example you want to communicate between Android components which singleton classes to use.

As an example you could have an action interface

```
public interface Action {
    void run(List<String> args, Context context);
}
```

that should perform specific tasks in a Fragment and you want to initialize Fragments with different sets of actions. Then your Fragment's instantiation methods can simply take `Action` classes as parameter:

```
public static void newInstance(String someParameter, Class<? extends Action>... actions) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    String[] actionNames = new String[actions.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < actionNames.length; i++) {
        actionNames[i] = actions[i].getCanonicalName();
    }
    arguments.putStringArray(ARG_ACTIONS, actionNames);
}
```

Having defined some classes `MyActionA implements Action` and `MyActionB implements Action` you would create a Fragment with these actions in the following way:

```
Fragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance("some parameter", MyActionA.class, MyActionB.class)
```

The Fragment itself can use a list of actions (`List<Action> action`) as member variable which is initialized from the Bundle in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    for (String actionName : getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_ACTIONS)) {
        try {
            Class<? extends Action> actionClass = (Class<? extends Action>) Class.forName(actionName);
            Action action = actionClass.newInstance();
            actions.put(action.getName(), action);
        } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This by the way would fail with anonymous classes when trying to instantiate them as `getCanonicalName()` returns `null` for anonymous classes. So this method cannot be used to pass around anonymous classes, which I doubt to be possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to put any object into a bundle. You can put only two types of classes into a bundle: those which implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

Comment: Actually, [`Class` implements `Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html). I don't know for certain that it will work properly, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare you're right, it should actually work. But what's the use of storing a `Class`? I was thinking of storing an object of that class. And `Object` doesn't implement `Serializable`.

Comment: Well, given the snippet of code in the question, my guess is that the OP is sending a `Class` over to an activity to tell it what sort of event to create, where that activity perhaps makes the event object via reflection. The problem with passing `EventClass` instances is that a `Bundle` is effectively pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference, which may preclude things like anonymous inner classes extending `EventClass`. That being said, as I noted in my comment on the question, I am skeptical that this is a good idea.

Comment: I agree with you on that skepsis. Sharing classes definetly shouldn't be done through serialization.

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick answer. I found a work around by using the Class name and no the type. Then I can create a new instance from a specific class name.